# Can I create fonts drawn as outlined in Word 16 for Mac?

Tags: macos, ms-office, font

I'm trying to make some colouring in pages for my daughter, and want to make a large letter per page for her to colour in.

On Windows I could select a letter, choose `font` and there's an `outline` option that I can check.

I can't see this on Microsoft Word for Mac - 16.23 - Office 365 Subscription.

Is anyone aware of ways to achieve this?

[image: Font options in Office on Windows]

[image: Font options in Office on Mac]

Comment: Are you using PowerPoint or Word and what license is applied? The same apps behave differently based on licensing now. An edit to show the version of a specific app might help us help you.

Comment: Microsoft Word for Mac - 16.23 - Office 365 Subscription

Answer (score 4):

Latest version of Word and works fine using Format and Font, with no fill and outline : 
[image]

Comment: That's what I was looking for, but can't see it on my version (image added to OP). What version are you using?

Comment: Office 365 latest version... I selected the text then format menu > font which brings that text selection box on rhs..

Answer (score 3):

If you have a problem with Word, Apple's standard TextEdit or Pages lets you do this via Format > Font > Outline.

Answer (score 2):

I'm stuck on Word 2011.  If I choose the Format | Font menu option I get a dialog box which has, at the bottom, a button labelled **Text Effects**.  Pressing that opens another dialog where setting Text Fill to *No Fill* and Text Line to black results in an outlined character.

I don't have a later version of Word to test this on, do let us know if this works for your version.

Comment: This is, strictly speaking, a different thing that achieves a similar effect. (Combining this with font outlines can, iirc, give you an outline of an outline.) But it _should_ be available on later versions, in a different menu.

Answer (score 2):

The version of Word that you have should include WordArt, which allows you to do outline text.

For example:

- Word 2016 for Mac: on the Insert tab, click WordArt.
- Word 2011 for Mac: on the Document Elements tab, under Text Elements, click WordArt, and then click the WordArt that you want.